# Combining SUM and CASE returns 0?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Against SQL Server, I'm essentially trying to calculate a value based on Year to Date, so I want to sum any values from July 16, 2012 and prior and display them.  I'm using the following query (note that I've replaced parameters with simple integers to calculate the value for today):

```
SELECT SUM(CASE 
        WHEN (
            (
                dns.ODAY <= 16
                AND (dns.fiscalyear + 1) = 13
                AND dns.omonth = 7
            )
            OR
               (
                (dns.fiscalyear + 1) = 13
                AND dns.omonth < 7
                )
            )

        THEN dns.QtyShipped
        ELSE 0
        END) AS Shipped_Units

FROM myTable dns
```

However, this query is returning 0 for all rows.  If I replace dns.QtyShipped with an integer, say 1, it still returns 0.  So obviously the case statement isn't being evaluated correctly.  Is my logic flawed?  Or is it a syntax issue (e.g. I need more parentheses)?

Thanks!

Additional comments:

To test, I've ran the following query:

```
SELECT SUM(dns.QtyShipped)
FROM myTable dns
where 
                    (dns.ODAY <= 16
                    AND (dns.fiscalyear + 1) = 13
                    AND dns.omonth = 7)

                    OR
                    ((dns.fiscalyear + 1) = 13
                    AND dns.omonth < 7)
```

Which returns a very large number.  This is confusing.

Comment: A) `(dns.fiscalyear + 1) = 13` is never true?; 
B) `dns.omonth` is always greater than 7?; 
C) Combinaison of the 2...

Can you post the dns table definition?

Comment: B) `dns.omonth < 7` is never true?

Comment: how do you know you have data that matches your case?

Comment: Good point.  I've edited my question to (I believe) show that I have data that matches my case.

Comment: Can you add the first record returned by each of your test queries to the question?

Comment: I didn't ask for the sum value, but for the first **record** (including all of the columns from the table, or at least all of the columns used in the query) returned by each of the test queries. This is so that the rest of us can try to duplicate your problem with a sample of the data **that you are actually using**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code that you mentioned earlier is working absolutely fine. Please double check the values you are using to evaluate the conditions. For example, please confirm if for fiscalyear the value is 2013 or 13. I've used variables instead of column names in the code mentioned below and its returning the expected results:

```
declare @ODAY integer
set @ODAY=17
declare @fiscalyear int
set @fiscalyear=12
declare @omonth int 
set @omonth=8

SELECT SUM(CASE 
    WHEN (
        (
            @ODAY <= 16
            AND (@fiscalyear + 1) = 13
            AND @omonth = 7
        )
        OR
           (
            (@fiscalyear + 1) = 13
            AND @omonth < 7
            )
        )

    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
    END) AS Shipped_Units
```

Answer (score 1):

If I had to guess I would say that  your year is being stored as 4 digits.  At least that is the problem I ran into when I set up my test.

When I set up this test it worked:

```
CREATE TABLE myTable (fiscalyear int, omonth int, ODAY int, qtyshipped int)
INSERT INTO myTable VALUES (2012,1,1,1),
(12,1,1,1),
(12,2,1,1),
(12,3,1,1),
(12,4,1,1),
(13,1,1,1),
(12,7,1,1)
```

When I set up this test it failed:

```
CREATE TABLE myTable (fiscalyear int, omonth int, ODAY int, qtyshipped int)
INSERT INTO myTable VALUES (2012,1,1,1),
(2012,1,1,1),
(2012,2,1,1),
(2012,3,1,1),
(2012,4,1,1),
(2013,1,1,1),
(2012,7,1,1)
```

Is there any reason you aren't using actual dates?  Your logic would be much simpler and if the dates are stored in your table then the query would probably be faster too.

EDIT: Here is an additional test you can run to be sure its your case causing the problem:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE 
        WHEN (
            (
                dns.ODAY <= 16
                AND (dns.fiscalyear + 1) = 13
                AND dns.omonth = 7
            )
            OR
               (
                (dns.fiscalyear + 1) = 13
                AND dns.omonth < 7
                )
            )

        THEN 0
        ELSE dns.QtyShipped
        END) AS Shipped_Units

FROM myTable dns
```

Basically flip the case around.  Return 0 if you are true and the QtyShipped if not.  If you get a value this way then the problem is in your case, if you don't then the problem is probably somewhere else in your query.

Comment: Unfortunately, the database was setup by our client years ago and doesn't adhere to best practices.  The years are indeed stored as two digit numbers, which is baffling.